# Running kivy on mac from terminal

Tags: python, terminal, kivy

I'm new to kivy, and I have created a small test app which is:

**testapp.py:**

```
 from kivy.app  import App
 #require ("3.7.0")

 from kivy.uix.label import label

 class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return label(text="Hello World!")

 if __name__=="__main__": 
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

This file is located in the Documents.
And when i try to run it by typing:

> python ./testapp.py

in the terminal.
However i got this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./testapp.py", line 1, in <module>
 from kivy.app  import App
 File "/Users/lamatatwany/Documents/kivy.py", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named app
```

I don't know what is wrong? I'm new to kivy so if someone please can help me with it..

Comment: Rename `kivy.py` to something else.

Comment: @KlausD. I already deleted this file.. is not there anymore

Comment: @KlausD. Actually there was kivy.pyc.. when i renamed it, it worked! Thank you :)